# In ensemble learning, does accuracy increase depending on the number of models you want to combine?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I want to predict using the same model as multivariate time series data in a time series prediction problem.

Example:

```
pa = model predict result(a)
pb = model predict result(b)
pc = model predict result(c)
...
model ensemble([pa, pb, pc,...]) -> predict(y)
```

Can I expect a better performance of our model by using a model ensemble with more kinds of time series data here?

Comment: Do you mean that would be a single model, but you have multiple timeseries with same target and you plan to ensemble prediction for these timeseries?

Comment: Yes. I want to make predictions with multiple time series data of different kinds with the same model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Let's say you have 5 classes named `a,b,c,d,e`. You fit your data into a SVM Classifier and a Random Forest Classifier. Assume that, SVM classified `"a"` and `"b"` class well and RFC classified `"c","d","e"` well. So, ensembling these two models is going to increase accuracy  dramatically. Ensemble learning is really good when a model generating many `"False-Positive"` and `"False-Negative"`. You can also use weighted ensemble learning methods. You can set greater weights for reliable models & lower weights for untrustable models.